# datatables.net searchbox ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to understand and test datatables.net and i know there is ajax call while I typing in search box, in case of server side processing, the query is sent to server by ajax,

[image]

this is the example I used in testing
https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

so where exactly can I find that ajax function corresponding to searchbox?

many thanks

Comment: did you try to inspect element?

Comment: this link may help you, https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()

Comment: @MathewMagante yes but element only reveals <input type="search" class="" placeholder="" aria-controls="itemDetailsTable">, which I can't find how ajax sends sql query out

Comment: i actually did read this datatables.net/reference/api/search()  but this is API for datatables object, it seems different from server-side ajax implementation

Answer (score 0):

There are two modes in jQuery DataTables:

- [Client-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/data/#Client-side-processing)
- [Server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/data/#Server-side-processing) ([`serverSide: true`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide))

With server-side processing, searching, ordering and pagination is performed by the server-side script. jQuery DataTables distribution includes PHP library that aids in handling server-side requests using PHP. You can find third-party libraries for other languages as well.

Below are the options that are related to Ajax request:

> [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
>
> [`ajax.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) Add or modify data submitted to the server upon an Ajax request
>
> [`ajax.dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) Data property or manipulation method for table data

From the [official documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax):

> As an object, the [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) object is passed to [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) allowing fine control of the Ajax request. DataTables has a number of default parameters which you can override using this option.